# Using ICEcoder on a GitHub page

Tags: javascript, github-pages

I know that this something that I should know but I haven't found anything similar from Google so I am asking here.

Is there a way to add [Monaco](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor) to my website as a sub page and if so, how do I do that? Because, I wanted to add a code editor on my personal Git website, just for giggles and it turns out  Monaco does exactly that.

Also, if that isn't possible, how about [ICEcoder](https://icecoder.net/), can I add that to my website? I am asking because it's the same thing and I don't know how to call a JavaScript or PHP application to a web-page and the closer I look, the harder it gets to find a tutorial or a step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

The *Monaco* repo you linked has a `gh-pages` branch with Monaco running on GitHub Pages.  You can see it here: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/index.html

You need to build it somewhere (e.g. by hand on your local machine or if you want to automate it, you can use e.g. Travis CI) and push it.

I'm not familiar with Monaco and therefore can't give you any detailed instructions on how to do that.

*ICEcoder* however requires PHP.  GitHub Pages only serves static files.  You can use it to deliver JavaScript to the browser and run it there, but anything that runs on the server (Node.js, PHP, Python, Go, ...) does not work with GitHub Pages. (Assuming you're not using [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/)).